# Where to put the SSL keystore (.jks) and how to access it from .jar?

Tags: java, mongodb, ssl, jar, keystore

I am working on a Java application that uses **SSL** to communicate with **MongoDb**. The application is designed to be packaged into a **.jar** file and then runs inside a Docker container. MongoDb requires you to setup JVM system properties in order to get SSL to work:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", pathToJKS);
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", pw);
```

My problem now is that I don't know where to put my .jks file and specify the correct path in order for my application to be able to access it at runtime?

Currently my .jks file is located in the resources folder (src/main/resources/store.jks), which is fine if I execute the app via IDE but of course as soon as the app is executed from a .jar file, I am getting a `java.io.FileNotFoundException`. Below is the code I am currently using to get the path.

```
boolean isIDE = ...;
String pathToJKS = isIDE ? "src/main/resources/store.jks" : getPathFromJar("store.jks");

public String getPathFromJar(String filename) {
    ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
    final URL resourceUrl = classLoader.getResource(filename);

    if (resourceUrl != null) {
        return resourceUrl.toExternalForm();
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**My question is where is the proper location to put the .jks file and how can I access it (via path) from a .jar file?**

Comment: Hey Philipp, have you found out any solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Is the same keystore used for all the environments? If so, then I would've included as you're currently doing. If not, then just add the keystore-path as a required parameter included in the startup, such as:

```
java -jar <jar-file>.jar -Dkeystore.location=/some/location/to/keystore.jks
```

Otherwise, the following should work in order to retrieve the jar-file located in the resources-folder:

```
//note the slash                       --v
theResource = MyClass.class.getResource("/store.jks");
// MyClass => class where the getPathFromJar()-method resides
```

Then just perform similar to this in order to load it (I guess this is already covered, but hey):

```
KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType()).load(theResource, password);
```

Answer (score 0):

In folder Created Test Class, subFolder src with keystore.jks file in it.

TestClass:

```
import java.io.*;
public class Test{

    public static void main(String... args){
        String fileName = args[0];
        new Test().readFile(fileName);

    }   

    void readFile(String fileName){

        try {
        InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(fileName);
        KeyStore keyStore =  KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        keyStore.load(in, "password".toCharArray());
        Enumeration enumeration = keyStore.aliases();
        while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
            String alias = (String)enumeration.nextElement();
            System.out.println("alias name: " + alias);
        }   

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }

}
```

Generated jar with following command:

```
jar cvfe test.jar Test *.class src/keystore.jks
```

Executed jar file and it reads keystore inside jar.

```
java -jar test.jar /src/keystore.jks
```